# Forcing the long word in the next line using custom font

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i am using word-wrap to break long word into next line but it is not working. This is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LU3kT/23/) code.

Basically my divs are generated dynamically. This is what i am doing

```
Reading the div value.
Adding word-wrap property in all the child divs
Adding a Custom Font
Auto Resizing the text to fill in the div.
```

I am adding word-wrap like this

```
//adding the word-wrap property
var target = $("#" + element);
target.find('*').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
    $(this).css('word-break', 'break-word');
    $(this).css('word-break', 'break-all');
});
```

But the result is not forcing the word in to the next line. Check my JsFiddle. What can i do to force the word into the next line?

Comment: why downvoted, any one can explain please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`css: word-wrap`, is different than `css: word-break`. The first can be set to `break-word`, the latter to `break-all`. You have set word-break twice in a row, overwriting the first setting, which wasn't really a setting, since it's not valid for `word-break`. And I assume you meant to use `word-wrap`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the word-break to word-wrap but still is the same. I want to force long words in to next line. If you check my code then adding the word-wrap stays the same

Comment: the fiddle you have, the second word is wider than its container. All the word-wrap and word-break css will do is decide how the word can be broken when pushed to the next line.

Comment: whoah, looking at that fiddle, you got all kinds of confusing and overlapping code. Your words are breaking because you have word-break set in the style of the divs themselves. If you remove all those styles and don't bother with it, then the 3 lines you have will all stay on their own lines.

Comment: Thanks but i can not remove the style that is already generated as i have mentioned earlier it is a dynamically generated divs so i do not want to change any design.